# random.choice displays an error

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to stack overflow and I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following question. If you know a similar question that was answered, please point me towards it. thanks:)

This is my code to create a function load_words() that creates a list of 6 letter words from the file "words.txt". I want the random.choice() to pick a random word from the list and save it into word. However, I get the error below.

```
    import random
    def load_words(filename, length):
        file = open(filename, "r")
        words = []
        for line in file:
            word = line.strip()
            if len(word)== length:
                words.append(word)
    return words
    word = random.choice(words)
    print (word)
```

the error I get is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\mssuk\Desktop\University\Software Engineering\Assignment\assignment 1 - word guessing game\compute_score.py", line 14, in <module>
    word = random.choice(words)
    NameError: name 'words' is not defined
```

Comment: there is no image, please simply copy/paste the error message

Comment: hey Gilles, sorry, I just edited it and added the error message

Answer (score 0):

It's an indentation error. Indent your return statement by 4 spaces and the code will work.

```
import random
def load_words(filename, length):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    words = []
    #Assuming there is only one word in a line
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        if len(word) == length:
            words.add(word)
    file.close()
    return words
word = random.choice(load_words(your_filename, your_length)
print(word)
```

Comment: Could you post two lines of your txt file? It would help in debugging.

Comment: abdomen
abdomens
abduct
abducting
abduction
abductions
abductor

Comment: Those are words in the words.txt file. each word has a new line. the edited program brings up the same issue. I am using python 3.6.2 if that makes any difference. Thank you :)

Comment: Try copy pasting the code I'm using. It seems to work for me.